# unable to get my proxy server to send http requested information to client- Socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, proxy, fork, http-request

My objective of my programs is to implement a proxy server that can be connected by a single client and would only allow http request.

**The Requirements**

1. To create a C based client-server architecture using sockets
2. The proxy server should be able to accept and service single client's http requests

---

Code

client.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int sockfd, portnum, n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;

char buffer[256];
if(argc < 3){
  fprintf(stderr, "usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
  exit(1);
}
portnum = atoi(argv[2]);
sockfd= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(sockfd <0){
 perror("ERROR opening Socket");
 exit(1);
}
server= gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if(sockfd  == NULL){
 fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
 exit(1);
}
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
     (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
      server->h_length); 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portnum);

if(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) <0){
 fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, on connecting");
 exit(1);
}
printf("Please enter the Host name: ");
bzero(buffer,256);
fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
n=write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if(n<0){
 printf("Error writing to socket");
 exit(1);
}

bzero(buffer,256);
n=read(sockfd,buffer,255);
if(n<0){
 printf("ERROR reading from socket");
 exit(1);
}
printf("%s\n", buffer);


    return 0;
    }
```

Proxy server.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <string.h>



    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int sockfd, newsockfd, portnum, clilen;
char buffer[256], hostname[256];
pid_t p_id;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int n, pid;

if(argc < 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, NO PORT PROVIDED!\n");
    exit(1);
}
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//socket is made

if(sockfd < 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR opening socket!!");
    exit(1);
}
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portnum = atoi(argv[1]);//port num

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portnum);


if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR on binding");
    exit(1);
}

if( listen(sockfd, 5) < 0){
 printf("ERROR ON LISTEN");
 exit(1);
}

    // accept
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    do{

newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
if(newsockfd<0){
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR on accept\n");
    exit(1);
}

    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){ 
bzero(buffer, 256);
n= read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);

if(n<0){//message from client
 fprintf(stderr,"ERROR Reading from socket\n");
 exit(1);
}   

strcpy(hostname, buffer);
printf("Here is the hostname : %s\n", hostname);

//variables used for acsessing webserver?
int sockwb, wbport, x;
struct sockaddr_in webser_addr;
struct hostent *wbhost;
char webbuf[510];//sending to webserver

wbport =80;//port used to access web server


    sockwb = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockwb <0){
        printf("error opeing websocket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    wbhost= gethostbyname(hostname);
    printf("%s", wbhost->h_name);
    if(sockwb == -1){
        printf("NO SUCH web HOST\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    bzero((char*) &webser_addr, sizeof(webser_addr));
    webser_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

        bcopy((char *)wbhost->h_addr,               
            (char *)&webser_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,       
            wbhost->h_length);              

    webser_addr.sin_port = htons(wbport);   
    if(connect(sockwb,(struct sockaddr *)&webser_addr,sizeof(webser_addr)) < 0){
        printf("error on web connecting\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    bzero(webbuf,510);
    strcpy(webbuf, "GET http://");
    strcat(webbuf, hostname);
    strcat(webbuf, " HTTP/1.1");

    printf("%s\n", webbuf);
    x=write(sockwb,webbuf,strlen(webbuf));
    if(x<0){
        printf("error writing to web sock");
        exit(1);
    }   
    bzero(webbuf,510);
    x=read(sockwb,webbuf,510);
    if(n<0){    
        printf("error reading from web socket");
        exit(1);
    }   

n = write(newsockfd, webbuf,255 );//write back to client

if (n<0){
   fprintf(stderr,"ERROR WRITING to socket");
   exit(1);
}

printf("%s\n", webbuf);
}//end of if pid==0

printf("closing client");
close(newsockfd);//closing client socket


    }while(1);
    return 0;
    }
```

---

I have been able to implement a simple client-server exchange with sockets, my issue is with the Http request. I do have to access the web server through port 80 using the GET Method.

The way i have the input that the client is sending to the proxy server should be :     www.NAME.com

The server doesn't seem to doing anything after the initial connection to the client.

Comment: Usual problems. No proper error handling. Ignoring the count returned by `recv()`. Unnecessary zeroing of buffers.

Comment: @EJP, The real problem is, as usual, not knowing how to manage null-terminated strings.

Comment: @SergeyA I can't agree with that formulation. There are no null-terminated string to handle in TCP. TCP code should not assume otherwise. It should use the count returned by `recv()`.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, null-terminated strings are not managed properly here. When following construct is used

```
send(sock, buff, strlen(buf));
```

The trailing null-terminated character is not sent. On the receiving side, there are two problems. First, `recv(sock, buff, sizeof(buff));` can receive unpredictable amount of bytes - from 1 to the size of the string provided. So you need to read until you read all the message. Here comes the dilemma - how do you know how long is the actual message? The answer is that you either agree on the size of all the strings in advance, and than you always send that many bytes (regardless of actual string length) or you prefix the the string with it's size in the message. The second problem is that even if by luck the whole string is read, it is not null-terminated, and as such, unusable in the program. It has be null-terminated manually.